# How to check an ELB is associated with any autoscaling group using Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elb, aws-auto-scaling

How can I check whether an AWS Elastic Load Balancer, Application Load Balancer or Network Load Balancer is associated with any Auto-Scaling group by passing the Load Balancer name or Load Balancer ARN using Boto3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`describe_auto_scaling_groups()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.describe_auto_scaling_groups) command returns a list of `LoadBalancerNames`.

Therefore, you will need to:

- Call `describe_auto_scaling_groups()` to obtain a list of Auto Scaling groups
- Loop through each returned group and look at the `LoadBalancerNames` list
- Compare the entries with your Load Balancer name of interest